# Qt5 and QtQuick 2 bindings for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, windows-installer, pyqt5

I want to use Qt5 and QtQuick2 with a binding such as PyQt, but it seems the only builds available for PyQt are for Python 3.3. Are there any bindings I can use with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about binary installers for Windows. The maintainer of PyQt5 has [made it very clear](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2013-October/033344.html) that he will not be providing them for PyQt5/Python2:

> >>> Are there any Windows binary installers for PyQt5 and Python 2.7?
>   >>
>   >> No, and I don't intend to provide any.
>   >
>   > Thanks. Any particular reason?
>
> 1. Incompatibilities between dependencies and compiler versions - there would be no support for QtWebKit.
> 2. I'm trying to limit the total number of installer I maintain.
> 3. I'm doing my bit to encourage people to move to Py3.
>
> PyQt5 for Py2 is fully supported, so there is nothing to stop anybody
>   else doing the work.

So you'd better have a *very* good reason for insisting on using Python2 with PyQt5, because you'll be commited to either maintaining Windows builds yourself, or relying on a third party to do it for you.

If you do a little web-searching, you will find a few binary installers out there, as well as instructions/tutorials for buidling them yourself. But I'm not going to endorse any of them here, because I haven't tried any of them myself (and have no intention of doing so).

Comment: That's too bad, I guess I have no choice but to upgrade my codebase to Python 3 :(

Comment: @ron975. Yes, it's time to bite the bullet. I also put it off for as long as I could, but FWIW, I'm really glad I did. Python3 really is a _much_ better language than Python2. Porting all my code was far from trivial, but nowhere near as bad as I thought it would be, and it actually resulted in quite a lot of improvements. But of course, that's easy for me to say _now_... ;-)